# How do I Connect to MySQL socket using Doctrine 1.2?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Following the directions at http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction-to-connections/en#dsn,-the-data-source-name:examples, I get the following error

```
Message: PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'unix(' (1)
```

The exact DSN I am using is "mysql://root@unix(/tmp/mysql.sock)/test"
Yes, root with no password via local unix socket.

This exact configuration works with phpMyAdmin, so I know the settings are valid. I've also tried with another user with password and got the same error.

What confuses me is why it's throwing the error about the host, when I'm trying connect via socket as the instructions provided.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine needs PDO-like query string, see if it matches yours:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Moreover, have a look at this:

[Doctrine (in symfony project) can not connect through socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916012/doctrine-in-symfony-project-can-not-connect-through-socket)

Comment: mysql:username=root;host=localhost;hostname=localhost;unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock;dbname=test
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Manager_Exception' with message 'No hostname set in data source name'
Even with host and hostname set it's giving that